# React-Query, error on mutation despite response 204

Tags: reactjs, api-platform.com, react-query

I'm trying to use a delete method of my api with react-query. I've tried this:

```
const { isLoading, mutate } = useMutation(() => api.remove(path, item.id), {
    onSuccess: () => {
        openModal();
        refetchData();
    },
});

...

<button onClick={() => mutate()}>Remove element</button>
```

But when it's execute i'm getting this error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Api.tsx:104
```

It's not a problem due to my api beacause despite this error message, the opperation is completed on database.
I've test it on Insomnia and it's working, i'm getting a 204.

Did I make somthing wrong on my code ?

Thanks in advence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing what `api.remove` is doing, so I have to guess there is some json parsing there that errors.

react-query doesn't care about status codes, it cares about a resolved promise  (results in `success` state) or a rejected promise (results in `error` state). If your client side api function has some javascript runtime error, it will result in error state because of it.

Comment: Ok my bad, on api.remove i was trying to parse an empty body... Thanks for the highlight and sorry I feel a bit stupid ^^'